# Need help with a command to find all filenames that are too long and delete from a directory

Tags: awk, find, filenames, delete

I have been using the following command:

```
find . | awk 'function base(f){sub(".*/", "", f); return f;} \
{print length(base($0)), $0}'| sort -nr | head -2
```

It will find some files that have filenames too long but not all and it does not delete them.

What can I use for a command to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have GNU `find`, you can use a regular expression to find files whose names exceed a given length. For example, this will find files whose names are 20 characters or more:

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*/[^/]{20,}$'
```

You can delete these files by adding `-delete`:

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*/[^/]{20,}$' -print -delete
```

Without GNU `find`, you can count `?`s:

```
find . -name '????????????????????*'
```

and delete files with `-exec rm`:

```
find . -name '????????????????????*' -type f -print -exec rm {} +
```

`-type f` ensures this only matches files, and `-exec rm {} +` instructs `find` to run `rm` with as many files as possible in one go. Alternatively, to delete anything regardless of type, use

```
find . -name '????????????????????*' -print -exec rm -rf {} +
```

If you want to construct the series of `?`, you can use

```
printf '%20s*' | tr ' ' '?'
```

(for 20 characters), thus

```
find . -name "$(printf '%20s*' | tr ' ' '?')" -print -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Comment: If you hate counting more than resorting to the absurd, you could always do `find . -name "$(perl -e 'print "?" x 20,"*"')"` :P

Comment: Yup, or `find . -name "$(printf '%20s*' | tr ' ' '?')"`!

Comment: I tried: find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*/[^/]{255,}$' but it does not find any of the files with filenames that are too long. I also tried 254 and still nothing. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: find . -name '????????????????????*' seems to be working with 255 '?'s haha. I understand the absurd part now. Can you breakdown the delete command "-exec rm {} +" 

execute remove? what is the brackets and +?

Comment: ^^^ Also, is there a progress option for this so i can see what is being deleted?

Comment: @linuxuser24569, you can use `find ... -delete -print` (`-delete` should be available at least in BSDs too)

Comment: so what i gather is the following command will find and delete all files or directories that are greater than 255 characters?    find . -name "$(perl -e 'print "?" x 255,"*"')" -delete -print

Comment: when i run find . -name '????????????????????*' -exec rm {} + i am getting the following error "Is a directory"

Comment: @linuxuser24569 the “Is a directory” error comes from running `rm` on a directory without `-rf`; see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Using `find` and `Perl`, removing file-names > 42 characters:

```
max=42
find . -print0 | perl -0sne 'unlink if length > $max' -- -max=$((max-2))
```

From `perldoc -f unlink`:

> unlink  Deletes a list of files. On success, it returns the number of files it successfully deleted. On failure, it returns false and sets $! (errno):

### Use with care ! You can destroy the whole system if you are not in the good directory

And the leading `./` takes 2 characters. That's why I substract `-2` in shell